# Do you have to use a sprite sheet with CCSpriteFrameCache?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Looking through tutorials and the `CCSpriteFrame` and `CCSpriteFrameCache` documentation, it looks like I need a plist like what's generated using TexturePacker.

Is there a way to just add individual images to the cache?

Or a way to create a `CCSpriteFrame` with an image? It looks like there was support for it in version 1.0.0 but it's not in 2.0.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: yes you can do that. But you don't want to do this because its impractical and a waste of time. The whole point of spriteframes is to define texture regions in a texture atlas. Just use spriteWithFile otherwise. But that doesn't scale well performance-wise.

Sooner or later you'll have to start using texture atlases, and use a good tool for it (TexturePacker is my favorite).

Comment: agree for TP ... most comprehensive, excellent results with pvr formats and compressions. As you say, probably sooner than later :)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I guess I'll suck it up and buy it. haha. It's not that expensive anyway. =]

Answer (score 1):

If you need help for sprite sheets, you can check out this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32045/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-2-x)
He shows you how to use `texture packer` and completely animate a bear. And texture packer makes the .plist for you automagically.  It is quite cool. However you do NOT need to use a sprite sheet. You can, I think, add the images to an array and play the sequence of images in the array as an animation. That tutorial is [here](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/02/28/uiimage-animation-tutorial/)
Also, all CCSpriteFrameCache does is cache the sprite frames. You can load the CCSpriteFrameCache with the frames using a .plist file or you can use CCSpriteFrame and a sprite frame name to load it into as well. Check this cocos2d forum out : [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/633)

Good luck =-)

Comment: yeah, I looked at that and was using that originally, but my free trial ran out so I was wondering if I could do it without it. =]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need texture packer to create a .plist ... vi will do just fine if you have the stomach for it. However, you could:

```
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 40); 
CCTexture2D *myTexture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"myTexture.pvr.gz"];
CCSpriteFrame *fr=[CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:myTexture rect:myRect];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFrame:fr name:@"myFunkyFrameName"];
```

ed. not tested but compiles fine with 2.0, should work.